# Where handler to resize column event in TreeGrid (extjs)?

Tags: extjs

Where handler to resize column event in TreeGrid (extjs)?

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more? Are you asking how to listen for the column resize event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you explain your question a bit more?
I'm guessing your looking for something like this:

```
var tg = new Ext.ux.TreeGrid({
          //set config properties....
});

tg.on('columnresize', function(colIndex, newSize){
     //doSomething.....
}, this);
```

Comment: wondering if you can help me out?  :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058921/configuration-required-to-get-sencha-extjs-treegrid-example-working

Answer (score 0):

As of EXTJS 4, the columnresize event has different callbacks FYI:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-columnresize