# Configuration required to get Sencha ExtJS TreeGrid example working

Tags: iis, configuration, extjs, treegrid

Can someone help explain what configuration I'm missing to get the Sencha Ext JS 4 framework TreeGrid sample working?

Here's what I've done so far:

Downloads:
http://php.iis.net > click "PHP on Windows" > install "PHP53.exe"
http://www.sencha.com > click "Products" > click "EXT JS 4" > extract zip file code and place into C:\source\ext-4.0.7-gpl

Turned on IIS 7 in Windows 7 Programs and Features

Created IIS 7 website in Windows 7:
- set physical path of website to "C:\source\ext-4.0.7-gpl" (setting root of site to *\docs seemed to break some of the examples)
- I didn't set any special bindings (just port 80) .. localhost is implied without setting it

To try and view the example, I did the following:
- navigate to http://localhost > click "View the Examples" > Scroll down to "Trees" section
- notice that the "Drag and Drop Reordering", "Multiple Trees", and "XML Tree" work in this section when you have PHP installed, but the "Tree Grid" and "Check Tree" do not.  I'm mostly interested in the "TreeGrid".

**What am I missing in my configuration or setup?**

=========================================================

## 2/13/2012 @10:51pm

I thought I had this one solved, but apparently not.  I left this project be for awhile, so I didn't confirm the answer.  The treegrid.json file is definitely there, and it matches the file on the sencha.com extjs tree grid example json file.

Here is the URL to my tree grid example (copied from Sencha's example):

http://24.177.214.232:8888/examples/tree/treegrid.html

Here is the URL to the Sencha.com tree grid example:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/tree/treegrid.html

Comment: Could you make an online sample page to found your issue ?

Comment: here you go.. I had to add an inbound firewall rule for port 8888 and change the binding, and add a line in my router port forwarding.  My ISP doesn't allow port 80.  http://24.177.214.232:8888/

Comment: have you tried using firefox + firebug to see if any error is reported?

Comment: seems like there's an error on line 17,836 in file... http://24.177.214.232:8888/ext-all-debug.js ... JavaScript Error: http://24.177.214.232:8888/examples/tree/treegrid.json?_dc=1327908284930&node=root&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22leaf%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%5D ..... this doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the other configuration described, I had to go into IIS and do the following before the Tree Grid worked:

- click on the new site
- click on MIME types
- right click in open space > Add > File name extension: "json" ... MIME Type: "application/x-javascript"

Answer (score 4):

if you inspect `treegrid.js` you'll see that it requires `treegrid.json` (JSON-formatted data file). when you visit http://24.177.214.232:8888/examples/tree/treegrid.json (which is the path where `treegrid.js` expects `treegrid.json`) you'll see, that there is no such file.

fix the path or create a data file : )

**EDIT**
you can find proper JSON here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/tree/treegrid.json

Comment: I'm an idiot for not checking JS errors when it's a JS framework.  :-)  I'll have to see what that file should look like tomorrow :-)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: so the example you posted is hard coded for the data in their site examples, right?  That would normally come from a dynamic AJAX JSON get or post call to get the real data, correct?

Comment: Indeed, the treegrid works, it's just the datafile that can't be loaded. Check for the existence of the .json file and make sure that it's publicly accessible by your browser.

Comment: @MacGyver you are correct. you can define different storages to load and save your data.

Comment: See update to question.  I hadn't touched this one for awhile, but when checking the directory for that json file, it's clearly there.  Now I don't get that error.  Do you have any other ideas for troubleshooting?